# I cant figure out to implement -1 as a sentinel value using a while loop.

Tags: java

I can't figure out to implement -1 as a sentinel value using a while loop. Note that the program needs to be running all times except when the users enter the value -1 it should stop. Technically the program should stop at any time when the user enters the sentinal value(-1).

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class Multi {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random rand = new Random();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int randomOne, randomTwo, product, userInput;

        while(true) {
        randomOne = Math.abs(rand.nextInt()%10);
        randomTwo = Math.abs(rand.nextInt()%10);

        product = randomOne * randomTwo;

        System.out.println("How much is " + randomOne + " times " + randomTwo 
        + "?");
        userInput = scan.nextInt();

        if (product == userInput) {
            System.out.println("Very Good!");
            }

        else {
        while (product != userInput) {
            System.out.println("No. Please try again.");
            System.out.println("How much is " + randomOne + " times " + 
         randomTwo + "?");
            userInput = scan.nextInt();

         if (product == userInput) {
                System.out.println("Very Good!");

        }
        }}


        }   
        }
        }
```

So at all times when we ask input from the user, if they enter -1 the program should stop.

Comment: well: you want 'every input to be tested if it is "-1"' -> you can't achieve it without actually testing every single input if it is -1.  ( Well you can create a "input" method calls scan.nextInt and does the test and call that  method for every input you need.. )

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the value is -1 upon every iteration and then write a break statement, but below is a slightly cleaner implementation.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Multi {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random rand = new Random();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int randomOne, randomTwo, product, userInput;
    boolean playingGame = true;

    while (playingGame) {
      randomOne = Math.abs(rand.nextInt() % 10);
      randomTwo = Math.abs(rand.nextInt() % 10);

      product = randomOne * randomTwo;

      System.out.println("How much is " + randomOne + " times " + randomTwo + "?");
      userInput = scan.nextInt();

      while (userInput != -1 && product != userInput) {
        System.out.println("No. Please try again.");
        System.out.println("How much is " + randomOne + " times " +
            randomTwo + "?");
        userInput = scan.nextInt();
      }
      if (product == userInput) {
        System.out.println("Very Good!");
      } else {
        playingGame = false;
      }
    }

    scan.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: That was like magic. Learned a lot. This got me held 5 hours plus in the compiler. I was not testing every user input which was a wrong approach. Once again thank you so much for the help.